# K-prototype in R: Error when including missing values

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I want to cluster data that includes categorical (dummies and variables with multiple categories) and numerical variables (normalised) and a substantial amount of missing values.
One reason why I want to use k-prototypes is that it can handle missing values.

I've used the package clustMixType to do the clustering in R, however, when I do not drop all observations with missing values, I get the error "((d1+d2)==0) keep.protos[m] <-- FALSE: Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

My first suspicion was that this might be caused by observations that only contain missing values but dropping them did not fix this. Only dropping all observations with missing in any variable gets the code to run.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause the error and how to fix it?

Comment: The pam function with Gower distance as computed by function daisy seems to do pretty much the same thing, and should work with missing values.

Comment: Generally one shouldn't expect R-functions the documentation of which doesn't make any reference to missing values to work with them. By the way, observations with only missing values generally will not make much sense in a cluster analysis (or in any other statistical analysis).

Comment: Thanks for the response. kproto allows to specify if missing values should be dropped or not. "In case of na.rm = FALSE: for each observation variables with missings are ignored (i.e. only the remaining variables are considered for distance computation). In consequence for observations with missings this might result in a change of variable’s weighting compared to the one specified by lambda." Thus I assumed that this would not be an issue. Agree with the second point. That was an oversight in the data cleaning. Will check if pam with Gower distance works better.

Comment: From running some simulations, the issue with the kproto command does not seem to be an issue with the NAs, as I can generate mixed data with 70% NAs and cluster the data without any problem. And looking at the code of the command it also seems to check itself if there are observations with only NAs. That makes me think it might be an issue with the data types. However, the categorical variables are defined as factors and the numerical variables as numerical, so not sure where things go wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately, calculating the dissimilarity matrix via daisy is requiring too much memory, so that does not seem like a feasible option.